# How to you combine two dataLayer variables into one in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

There are two dataLayer variables on the page. How do you combine both of them into one single variable so that it can be pushed into analytics ?

dataLayer current format 
PageName: AIR_SEARCH_PAGE
Flow:BOOKING

I want to create another variable which is XYZ and the result to be displayed as BOOKING:AIR_SEARCH_PAGE. How to achieve this ?
XYZ:BOOKING:AIR_SEARCH_PAGE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options here:

1. Combine the strings through GTM. For example, looks like you have the following dataLayer:

   ```
   dataLayer = [{
   'PageName': 'AIR_SEARCH_PAGE',
   'Flow': 'BOOKING'
   }]
   ```

   In GTM, you could create a DL variable for 'PageName', and another one for 'Flow', and then when you need to combine them, or add other text around it, you can say:

   ```
   XYZ: {{Flow}}: {{PageName}}
   ```

   so this would render as "XYZ: BOOKING: AIR_SEARCH_PAGE"
2. Use the JS string manipulation and join the strings together and then push to the dataLayer again.
3. Push a new parameter into the dataLayer that combines the strings for you.

   ```
   dataLayer.push({
      'xyz': 'BOOKING:AIR_SEARCH_PAGE'
   })
   ```

   and then use that new variable through GTM.

I think the first method may be best.

Comment: http://test.gotossle.com/examples.nfshost.com/travel/checkout.html
i tried to add these two existing DataLayer Variable but seems this is not working or I am missing something :(
<script>
  dataLayer.push({'customerClass': 'customerCode'})
</script>

Comment: Which are your keys and which are your values? You need push them to the dataLayer in pairs: dataLayer.push({'key1': value1, 'key2': value2});

Comment: My tubelight lit today :)

Comment: That is awesome!!! I've waited soooo long for this day to come! Congratulations! What's a tubelight? :)

Comment: Tubelights generally take long time before it is completely lit. So while you gave the correct answer, tubelight of my brain took really long time to understand it. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are already set in GTM then create a Custom JavaScript variable to combine them -

```
function() {
  
  return {{Data Layer - pg_language}} + "-" + {{Data Layer - pg_country}};    
}
```