# Combining two datalayer variables through calculation in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

In Google Tag Manager, I have one datalayer variable named "transactiontotal" and I have one datalayer variable named "shippingcosts". What I want to do here is subtract "shippingcosts" from "transactiontotal" which would equate to (transactiontotal-shippingcosts) and make this a new variable "transactiontotalexcludingshipping".

Already saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070216/how-to-you-combine-two-datalayer-variables-into-one-in-google-tag-manager) on combing two string variables into one. What I'm specifically looking for is two combine two datalayer variables which are integers through calculation.

I've already used this [variable explanation guide](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/) to see whether Google Tag Manager has a variable such as calculated fields which would support above mentioned function, but the guide doesn't seem to mention that as a possibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing special about subtracting number in GTM, it's just plain JS. You address your variables by their names in {{double curly parenthesis}}.

Create a custom javascript variable called "transactiontotalexcludingshipping", which expects a anonymous function with a return value as body:

```
function() {
  return {{transactiontotal}} - {{shippingcosts}};
}
```

The double parenthesis allow you to reference your existing variables by name, and from there on it's straight subtraction. If you expect your variables at any point to have no value or a a wrong value you might want to add a little error checking.